# Is it possible to call a batch file from watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to call a batch file from watir-webdriver. I am using ruby with watir. I tried to use `system(filename.bat)` but it doesn't work.

I have written a step definition for this and when I run it I got an error stack level too deep (SystemStackError).

```
And(/^I execute a batch file$/) do
  system('filename.bat')
end
```

Comment: Calling a batch file would be a Ruby thing rather than a Watir thing. Using `system` should work, though, at least in your sample code, you are missing quotations around the file name - ie you need to pass in a String. If that's not the problem, you need to expand your question - ex what does "doesn't work" mean? Is there an exception?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the step definition, which means the problem occurs within the batch file. You will need to share the batch file's code.

Comment: Or possibly the batch file is not accessible because it isn't in the execution path. I believe that is relative to the starting directory unless you are calling Dir in other steps. Why would you want to call a batch file?